# Why is the energy of Gamma and Alpha radiation discrete while the energy of Beta radiation is not?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Why is the energy of Gamma and Alpha radiation discrete while the energy of Beta radiation is not?
Why is the energy from gamma radiation discrete, and how come the energy from Beta decay is not discrete?

Comment: Do you mean why does beta radiation have a continuous energy spectrum? If so, it's the neutrinos' fault!

Comment: @JohnRennie that sounds like an answer masquerading as a comment.

Comment: @DanielSank: I'm genuinely unclear what is being asked here. In fact I have VTC'd as unclear and will withdraw the vote only if the question is clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are nuclear decays. Alpha and gamma are two body decays, transitions in energy levels . Beta decay is the decay of a neutron given the possibility from the energy balances.

The neutron is a three body decay, and thus the electron will have a spectrum. That was the way the [neutrino was discovered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Pauli.27s_proposal), balancing the energy and momentum to a two body , neutron-remaining nucleus.